# Is there any way to cash in a pension fund?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, withdrawal

The last company I worked for (I'm in in the United Kingdom) had one of those schemes where the company puts a certain amount of money every month into a pension fund.  I quit my job and now I keep getting letters about my fund.  It's not a huge sum, just a couple thousand pounds.

I don't want a pension fund, and want to cash it in if at all possible.  (I know most of you will not understand this but I don't want to discuss it so if you choose to answer please respect my wishes.)

I've asked around, and it seems I can get it transferred, but I haven't found a way to extract any money from it.  Is there any way to cash it in?  I will gladly take £100 now rather than shut it down.  (As I mentioned, keeping it open is not an option.)

Is there any strategy I may have missed?  e.g. would I possibly be able to transfer the funds to someone else?  (Maybe in exchange for cash?)

Comment: Did you ask the benefits department of the company? In the states, some pensions have such a cash-out option, and some are locked in till retirement. Only your company can tell you the options you have.

Answer (score 2):

For "Small" or "Trivial" pensions you may be able to do this the rules recently changed check the pensions advisory service.

http://www.pensionsadvisoryservice.org.uk/news/2014/march/new-rules-for-cashing-in-your-pension

Comment: "as long as the provider allows" - as I commented.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer well they have just announced major changes to the UK pension system so that might not apply in the near future - the details are still being worked out